# Laplace transform of the autocorrelation of a wss random process

Tags: stochastic-processes, laplace-transform

Consider a wide-sense-stationary random process $x(t)$. The autocorrelation function is $r(t-\tau):=E[x(t)x(\tau)]$. Let $S(s)$ be the Laplace-transform of $r(t)$. Can I compute $S(s)$ as $S(s)=E[X(s)X(s)^*]$, where $X(s)$ is the Laplace transform of $x(t)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing the **definition** of $S$ yields $S(s)=E(X(s)x(0)^*)=s\,E(X(s)X(s)^*)$.

**Edit:** To show the rightmost identity, start from $$E(X(s)X(s)^*)=\iint E(x(t)x(u)^*)\mathrm e^{-st}\mathrm e^{-su}\mathrm du\mathrm dt=2\int_0^\infty\int_t^\infty r(u-t)\mathrm e^{-s(t+u)}\mathrm du\mathrm dt,$$ and use the change of variable $v=u-t$, $w=t$, to reach the formula $$E(X(s)X(s)^*)=2\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty r(v)\mathrm e^{-s(2w+v)}\mathrm dv\mathrm dw=2S(s)\int_0^\infty\mathrm e^{-2sw}\mathrm dw,$$ which should be enough to conclude.

Comment: Cool! I got as far as $S(s)=E(X(s)x(0)^*)$, but may you please also give me some detail on how to get the rightmost term? Thanks so much!

Comment: See Edit. $ $ $ $

Comment: Great! I understand now, thanks again!

Comment: I just thought, do we maybe need to add a conjugate on the third "$s$"? In that case the result would be $$S(s)=sE[X(s)X(s^*)^*]$$. If we don't do so I think we get a conjugate symbol in the integral and I cannot get rid of it.

Comment: Hmmm... Recall that $t$, $u$, $v$ and $w$ in the answer are "times", that is, real numbers, and that $s$ is the argument of the Laplace transform, that is, a nonnegative real number. The quantities with values in the vector state-space of the process are $x(t)$, $X(s)$ and $S(s)$. Which is why in your post, $r(t-\tau)$ should read $E(x(t)x(\tau)^*)$, not $E(x(t)x(\tau))$... :-)